# Can I write web services in the Windows 7 API?

Tags: web-services, windows-7

Can I write web services in the Windows 7 API?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to indicate "yes".

Comment: Web services can be written in managed code (WCF) or native (Windows Web Services, as in the link.) Either way you write them, they can be installed on Windows 7 or called from Windows 7. Are you asking how to write them in C++ or whether they will work / can be installed on Windows 7?